# How to fetch twitter profile picture URL from the profile link?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, twitter, google-sheets-formula

How can I fetch profile picture URL from the profile link of a Twitter account in Google Sheets?

For example,
[image]

I will put profile link manually in column A and I want profile picture URL generated in the next cell.

Thank you in advance.

I checked all the existing questions and answers but no one has explained how to do this effectively using Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this API self made service from this guys:

```
https://ssbytes.com/api/twitterdp.php?q=fractefactos
```

You only need to change the q parameter.